# Time series data outlier detection using R

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

I am new to R. I have a time series data with days and value. The observations are grouped by id. For example:

```
    id value days
     101    0.9    1
     101    0.6    2
     101    0.4    3
     101     NA    4
     101    0.7    5
     102    0.6    1
     102    0.7    2
     102    0.9    3
     102    1.6    4
     102    0.5    5
     102     NA    6
     102     NA    7
     102    3.2    8
     102    3.1    9
     102    3.2    10
```

I would like to detect outliers of the time series data grouped by id. I did some research before and I can detect outliers for one single group using the tsoutlier package. Actually, this dataset is really large. So how can I effectively convert the data frame into a time series object, apply tso function to each group, and figure out all the outliers in the data set?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're able to accomplish this with a single group, have you checked out how sapply or lapply works?

Comment: What have tried? provide the code for one id (`tsoutliers`).